# Extract every fifth value from matrix

Tags: matlab

So I have 2d matrix and I want to extract every fifth value from the second column.

I know how to get all the values from the second column -

```
var = myMatrix(:,2);
```

But how can I only select every fifth value instead of all the values

Comment: I am confused what this 5th value is...as there are only 4 values in 2X2 matrix?!

Comment: Also, `myMatrix(:,1)` returns the first column

Comment: oops, meant 2d matrix..fixed the other error too. I need to get the values in position 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, .....etc

Comment: @JohnMcDonald: There is no value at position 0. So do you want 5,10,15 or 1,6,11?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891427/matlab-extract-every-nth-element-of-vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on exactly what "every fifth value" means, I think that what you want is:

```
var = myMatrix(5:5:end, 2);
```

which returns

```
var = [myMatrix(5,2); myMatrix(10,2); ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the mistake that sans481 has already pointed out to you, you would use array subscript triples.  For example, if your array A was 8x8 then

```
A(2,2:3:8)
```

would pick out row 2, columns 2,3,8, only.